# How would this OLED be mounted if in a commercial device?

Tags: 3d-design

I am making homebrew electronic items and I'm using this OLED, a 0.96" SSD1306 Module; very common in the Arduino world:

[image: Photo of OLED screen]

If someone were making a commercial device with this and designing a case, how would they mount this? We obviously see the 4 screw holes at the corners, but if you looked at this device from the side, you'll notice the glass is only about 1.2 mm proud of the PCB. In addition, if you solder headers to the 4 terminals, which is the common use, the end of the headers are actually flush with the glass.

Should the screws be coming through the case from the outside, through the PCB holes, with a nut on the other side? Would the glass normally be covered with acrylic rather than flush with the outside of the case?

So what's typical in this situation? This is a 3D-printed enclosure, so I'm also limited by that aspect of the design.

Comment: Are you 3D printing the enclosure? I ask since I don't see the 3D printing aspect in your question and that could cause your question to be closed for not being [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, this is a 3d printed enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

When I printed the case for my Arduino test setup, I used the screen measurements for the opening. Then I added stand-offs for the screw holes to rest on so that the glass was against the wall. I gently filed the solder flush to just below the plane of the glass. I used 2 mm by 3 mm screws to attach it. Make sure your wall thickness is enough so the screw doesn't penetrate, just for appearance. I will check my CAD file to try to get you the measurements if you like. I hope this helped some.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow. Any pics you can get me of your actual device?